# Insert row into Excel spreadsheet using openpyxl in Python

Tags: python, excel, xlrd, xlwt, openpyxl

I'm looking for the best approach for inserting a row into a spreadsheet using openpyxl.

Effectively, I have a spreadsheet (Excel 2007) which has a header row, followed by (at most) a few thousand rows of data. I'm looking to insert the row as the first row of actual data, so after the header. My understanding is that the append function is suitable for adding content to *the end* of the file.

Reading the documentation for both openpyxl and xlrd (and xlwt), I can't find any clear cut ways of doing this, beyond looping through the content manually and inserting into a new sheet (after inserting the required row).

Given my so far limited experience with Python, I'm trying to understand if this is indeed the best option to take (the most pythonic!), and if so could someone provide an explicit example. Specifically can I read and write rows with openpyxl or do I have to access cells? Additionally can I (over)write the same file(name)?

Comment: Do you have the option of exporting to CSV? And is this one time process? or do you need to do this repeatedly?

Comment: @Srini no, we're stuck with this format, and this is a repeatable process: The file actually gets FTP'd to another server and processed by an SSIS package.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Answering this with the code that I'm now using to achieve the desired result. Note that I am manually inserting the row at position 1, but that should be easy enough to adjust for specific needs. You could also easily tweak this to insert more than one row, and simply populate the rest of the data starting at the relevant position.

Also, note that due to downstream dependencies, we are manually specifying data from 'Sheet1', and the data is getting copied to a new sheet which is inserted at the beginning of the workbook, whilst renaming the original worksheet to 'Sheet1.5'.

EDIT: I've also added (later on) a change to the format_code to fix issues where the default copy operation here removes all formatting: `new_cell.style.number_format.format_code = 'mm/dd/yyyy'`. I couldn't find any documentation that this was settable, it was more of a case of trial and error!

Lastly, don't forget this example is saving over the original. You can change the save path where applicable to avoid this.

```
    import openpyxl

    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file)
    old_sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
    old_sheet.title = 'Sheet1.5'
    max_row = old_sheet.get_highest_row()
    max_col = old_sheet.get_highest_column()
    wb.create_sheet(0, 'Sheet1')

    new_sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

    # Do the header.
    for col_num in range(0, max_col):
        new_sheet.cell(row=0, column=col_num).value = old_sheet.cell(row=0, column=col_num).value

    # The row to be inserted. We're manually populating each cell.
    new_sheet.cell(row=1, column=0).value = 'DUMMY'
    new_sheet.cell(row=1, column=1).value = 'DUMMY'

    # Now do the rest of it. Note the row offset.
    for row_num in range(1, max_row):
        for col_num in range (0, max_col):
            new_sheet.cell(row = (row_num + 1), column = col_num).value = old_sheet.cell(row = row_num, column = col_num).value

    wb.save(file)
```

Comment: This manipulates the file as expected, although I feel I should add that we have now decided to implement a CSV export instead. This is because of encoding issues with the openpyxl library that are off topic for this question, but I felt I should mention it!

Answer (score 18):

== Updated to a fully functional version, based on feedback here: groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/openpyxl-users/wHGecdQg3Iw. ==

As the others have pointed out, `openpyxl` does not provide this functionality, but I have extended the `Worksheet` class as follows to implement inserting rows. Hope this proves useful to others.

```
def insert_rows(self, row_idx, cnt, above=False, copy_style=True, fill_formulae=True):
    """Inserts new (empty) rows into worksheet at specified row index.

    :param row_idx: Row index specifying where to insert new rows.
    :param cnt: Number of rows to insert.
    :param above: Set True to insert rows above specified row index.
    :param copy_style: Set True if new rows should copy style of immediately above row.
    :param fill_formulae: Set True if new rows should take on formula from immediately above row, filled with references new to rows.

    Usage:

    * insert_rows(2, 10, above=True, copy_style=False)

    """
    CELL_RE  = re.compile("(?P<col>\$?[A-Z]+)(?P<row>\$?\d+)")

    row_idx = row_idx - 1 if above else row_idx

    def replace(m):
        row = m.group('row')
        prefix = "$" if row.find("$") != -1 else ""
        row = int(row.replace("$",""))
        row += cnt if row > row_idx else 0
        return m.group('col') + prefix + str(row)

    # First, we shift all cells down cnt rows...
    old_cells = set()
    old_fas   = set()
    new_cells = dict()
    new_fas   = dict()
    for c in self._cells.values():

        old_coor = c.coordinate

        # Shift all references to anything below row_idx
        if c.data_type == Cell.TYPE_FORMULA:
            c.value = CELL_RE.sub(
                replace,
                c.value
            )
            # Here, we need to properly update the formula references to reflect new row indices
            if old_coor in self.formula_attributes and 'ref' in self.formula_attributes[old_coor]:
                self.formula_attributes[old_coor]['ref'] = CELL_RE.sub(
                    replace,
                    self.formula_attributes[old_coor]['ref']
                )

        # Do the magic to set up our actual shift    
        if c.row > row_idx:
            old_coor = c.coordinate
            old_cells.add((c.row,c.col_idx))
            c.row += cnt
            new_cells[(c.row,c.col_idx)] = c
            if old_coor in self.formula_attributes:
                old_fas.add(old_coor)
                fa = self.formula_attributes[old_coor].copy()
                new_fas[c.coordinate] = fa

    for coor in old_cells:
        del self._cells[coor]
    self._cells.update(new_cells)

    for fa in old_fas:
        del self.formula_attributes[fa]
    self.formula_attributes.update(new_fas)

    # Next, we need to shift all the Row Dimensions below our new rows down by cnt...
    for row in range(len(self.row_dimensions)-1+cnt,row_idx+cnt,-1):
        new_rd = copy.copy(self.row_dimensions[row-cnt])
        new_rd.index = row
        self.row_dimensions[row] = new_rd
        del self.row_dimensions[row-cnt]

    # Now, create our new rows, with all the pretty cells
    row_idx += 1
    for row in range(row_idx,row_idx+cnt):
        # Create a Row Dimension for our new row
        new_rd = copy.copy(self.row_dimensions[row-1])
        new_rd.index = row
        self.row_dimensions[row] = new_rd
        for col in range(1,self.max_column):
            col = get_column_letter(col)
            cell = self.cell('%s%d'%(col,row))
            cell.value = None
            source = self.cell('%s%d'%(col,row-1))
            if copy_style:
                cell.number_format = source.number_format
                cell.font      = source.font.copy()
                cell.alignment = source.alignment.copy()
                cell.border    = source.border.copy()
                cell.fill      = source.fill.copy()
            if fill_formulae and source.data_type == Cell.TYPE_FORMULA:
                s_coor = source.coordinate
                if s_coor in self.formula_attributes and 'ref' not in self.formula_attributes[s_coor]:
                    fa = self.formula_attributes[s_coor].copy()
                    self.formula_attributes[cell.coordinate] = fa
                # print("Copying formula from cell %s%d to %s%d"%(col,row-1,col,row))
                cell.value = re.sub(
                    "(\$?[A-Z]{1,3}\$?)%d"%(row - 1),
                    lambda m: m.group(1) + str(row),
                    source.value
                )   
                cell.data_type = Cell.TYPE_FORMULA

    # Check for Merged Cell Ranges that need to be expanded to contain new cells
    for cr_idx, cr in enumerate(self.merged_cell_ranges):
        self.merged_cell_ranges[cr_idx] = CELL_RE.sub(
            replace,
            cr
        )

Worksheet.insert_rows = insert_rows
```

Comment: Copying sounds like overkill. You might like to try something like the suggestion I made on the mailing list for inserting columns https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/openpyxl-users/wHGecdQg3Iw It's untested and 2.2 specific, because it relies on internals, but it gives the general thrust.

Comment: I agree that modifying the coordinate data is ideal, but this was done without looking into the internals. Not sure why the team will not just add this functionality, as it is something that is used very often in Excel.

Comment: No one has submitted the relevant code. openpyxl is open source, there is no team.

Comment: Dallas: How often something is used has no impact on how easy it is to implement. As @CharlieClark, there's no "team" (and he should know!).  This is an open source project based off phpexcel.  Significant changes to the cell/coordinate systems have been made as this project continues to mature.  These changes were needed for the requested functionality, otherwise solutions (like mine above) would be unreliable at best, and not suited for a major release. Give it time (or better, contribute!) for the functionality to be implemented.

Comment: Please see my Snippit in the repository. I have implemented this further...I would say pretty close to fully. ;^)

Comment: Hi Everyone, we're facing the same issue for your development, but not able overcome this issue with @Dallas code, please suggest us an approach to overcome the issue

Answer (score 15):

Adding an answer applicable to more recent releases, v2.5+, of `openpyxl`:

There's now an [`insert_rows()`](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.insert_rows) and `insert_cols()`.

> `insert_rows(idx, amount=1)`
>
> Insert row or rows before row==idx

Comment: Sadly it doesn't support merged cells (they stay fixed in their row position)

Answer (score 5):

Openpyxl Worksheets have limited functionality when it comes to doing row or column level operations.  The only properties a Worksheet has that relates to rows/columns are the properties `row_dimensions` and `column_dimensions`, which store "RowDimensions" and "ColumnDimensions" objects for each row and column, respectively.  These dictionaries are also used in function like `get_highest_row()` and `get_highest_column()`.

Everything else operates on a cell level, with Cell objects being tracked in the dictionary, `_cells` (and their style tracked in the dictionary `_styles`).  Most functions that look like they're doing anything on a row or column level are actually operating on a range of cells (such as the aforementioned `append()`).

The simplest thing to do would be what you suggested: create a new sheet, append your header row, append your new data rows, append your old data rows, delete the old sheet, then rename your new sheet to the old one.  Problems that may be presented with this method is the loss of row/column dimensions attributes and cell styles, unless you specifically copy them, too.

Alternatively, you could create your own functions that insert rows or columns.

I had a large number of *very* simple worksheets that I needed to delete columns from.  Since you asked for explicit examples, I'll provide the function I quickly threw together to do this:

```
from openpyxl.cell import get_column_letter

def ws_delete_column(sheet, del_column):

    for row_num in range(1, sheet.get_highest_row()+1):
        for col_num in range(del_column, sheet.get_highest_column()+1):

            coordinate = '%s%s' % (get_column_letter(col_num),
                                   row_num)
            adj_coordinate = '%s%s' % (get_column_letter(col_num + 1),
                                       row_num)

            # Handle Styles.
            # This is important to do if you have any differing
            # 'types' of data being stored, as you may otherwise get
            # an output Worksheet that's got improperly formatted cells.
            # Or worse, an error gets thrown because you tried to copy
            # a string value into a cell that's styled as a date.

            if adj_coordinate in sheet._styles:
                sheet._styles[coordinate] = sheet._styles[adj_coordinate]
                sheet._styles.pop(adj_coordinate, None)
            else:
                sheet._styles.pop(coordinate, None)

            if adj_coordinate in sheet._cells:
                sheet._cells[coordinate] = sheet._cells[adj_coordinate]
                sheet._cells[coordinate].column = get_column_letter(col_num)
                sheet._cells[coordinate].row = row_num
                sheet._cells[coordinate].coordinate = coordinate

                sheet._cells.pop(adj_coordinate, None)
            else:
                sheet._cells.pop(coordinate, None)

        # sheet.garbage_collect()
```

I pass it the worksheet that I'm working with, and the column number I want deleted, and away it goes.  I know it isn't exactly what you wanted, but I hope this information helped!

**EDIT:** Noticed someone gave this another vote, and figured I should update it.  The co-ordinate system in Openpyxl experienced some changes sometime in the passed couple years, introducing a `coordinate` attribute for items in `_cell`.  This needs to be edited, too, or the rows will be left blank (instead of deleted), and Excel will throw an error about problems with the file.  This works for Openpyxl 2.2.3 (untested with later versions)

Answer (score 5):

As of openpyxl 1.5 you can now use .insert_rows(idx, row_qty)

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook('excel_template.xlsx')
ws = wb.active
ws.insert_rows(14, 10)
```

It will not pick up the formatting of the idx row as it would if you did this manually in Excel. you will have apply the correct formatting i.e. cell color afterwards.

Answer (score 4):

To insert row into Excel spreadsheet using openpyxl in Python

Below code can help you :-

```
import openpyxl

file = "xyz.xlsx"
#loading XL sheet bassed on file name provided by user
book = openpyxl.load_workbook(file)
#opening sheet whose index no is 0
sheet = book.worksheets[0]

#insert_rows(idx, amount=1) Insert row or rows before row==idx, amount will be no of 
#rows you want to add and it's optional
sheet.insert_rows(13)
```

For inserting column also openpyxl have similar function i.e.insert_cols(idx, amount=1)

Answer (score 2):

I've written a function which will both insert an entire row anywhere you want in a spreadsheet, or an entire 2D table, with openpyxl.

Every row of the function is explained with a comment but if you want to just insert a single row, just make your row equal to [row]. i.e. if row = [1,2,3,4,5] then set your input to [[1,2,3,4,5]]. If you want this row to be inserted into the top row of your spreadsheet (A1) then Start = [1,1].

You can indeed overwrite the file name as see you can with my example at the bottom.

```
def InputList(Start, List): #This function is to input an array/list from a input start point; len(Start) must equal 2, where Start = [1,1] is cell 1A. List must be a two dimensional array; if you wish to input a single row then this can be done where len(List) == 1, e.g. List = [[1,2,3,4]]
    x = 0 #Sets up a veriable to go through List columns
    y = 0 #Sets up a veriable to go through List rows
    l = 0 #Sets up a veriable to count addional columns against Start[1] to allow for column reset on each new row
    for row in List: #For every row in List
        l = 0 #Set additonal columns to zero
        for cell in row: #For every cell in row
            ws.cell(row=Start[0], column=Start[1]).value = List[y][x] #Set value for current cell
            x = x + 1 #Move to next data input (List) column
            Start[1] = Start[1] + 1 #Move to next Excel column
            l = l + 1 #Count addional row length
        y = y + 1 #Move to next Excel row
        Start[0] = Start[0] + 1 #Move to next Excel row
        x = 0 #Move back to first column of input data (ready for next row)
        Start[1] = Start[1] - l #Reset Excel column back to orignal start column, ready to write next row
```

Example with single row being inserted at start of row 7:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook('New3.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

def InputList(Start, List): #This function is to input an array/list from a input start point; len(Start) must equal 2, where Start = [1,1] is cell 1A. List must be a two dimensional array; if you wish to input a single row then this can be done where len(List) == 1, e.g. List = [[1,2,3,4]]
    x = 0 #Sets up a veriable to go through List columns
    y = 0 #Sets up a veriable to go through List rows
    l = 0 #Sets up a veriable to count addional columns against Start[1] to allow for column reset on each new row
    for row in List: #For every row in List
        l = 0 #Set additonal columns to zero
        for cell in row: #For every cell in row
            ws.cell(row=Start[0], column=Start[1]).value = List[y][x] #Set value for current cell
            x = x + 1 #Move to next data input (List) column
            Start[1] = Start[1] + 1 #Move to next Excel column
            l = l + 1 #Count addional row length
        y = y + 1 #Move to next Excel row
        Start[0] = Start[0] + 1 #Move to next Excel row
        x = 0 #Move back to first column of input data (ready for next row)
        Start[1] = Start[1] - l #Reset Excel column back to orignal start column, ready to write next row

test = [[1,2,3,4]]
InputList([7,1], test)

wb.save('New3.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 1):

I took Dallas solution and added support for merged cells:

```
    def insert_rows(self, row_idx, cnt, above=False, copy_style=True, fill_formulae=True):
        skip_list = []
        try:
            idx = row_idx - 1 if above else row_idx
            for (new, old) in zip(range(self.max_row+cnt,idx+cnt,-1),range(self.max_row,idx,-1)):
                for c_idx in range(1,self.max_column):
                  col = self.cell(row=1, column=c_idx).column #get_column_letter(c_idx)
                  print("Copying %s%d to %s%d."%(col,old,col,new))
                  source = self["%s%d"%(col,old)]
                  target = self["%s%d"%(col,new)]
                  if source.coordinate in skip_list:
                      continue

                  if source.coordinate in self.merged_cells:
                      # This is a merged cell
                      for _range in self.merged_cell_ranges:
                          merged_cells_list = [x for x in cells_from_range(_range)][0]
                          if source.coordinate in merged_cells_list:
                              skip_list = merged_cells_list
                              self.unmerge_cells(_range)
                              new_range = re.sub(str(old),str(new),_range)
                              self.merge_cells(new_range)
                              break

                  if source.data_type == Cell.TYPE_FORMULA:
                    target.value = re.sub(
                      "(\$?[A-Z]{1,3})%d"%(old),
                      lambda m: m.group(1) + str(new),
                      source.value
                    )
                  else:
                    target.value = source.value
                  target.number_format = source.number_format
                  target.font   = source.font.copy()
                  target.alignment = source.alignment.copy()
                  target.border = source.border.copy()
                  target.fill   = source.fill.copy()
            idx = idx + 1
            for row in range(idx,idx+cnt):
                for c_idx in range(1,self.max_column):
                  col = self.cell(row=1, column=c_idx).column #get_column_letter(c_idx)
                  #print("Clearing value in cell %s%d"%(col,row))
                  cell = self["%s%d"%(col,row)]
                  cell.value = None
                  source = self["%s%d"%(col,row-1)]
                  if copy_style:
                    cell.number_format = source.number_format
                    cell.font      = source.font.copy()
                    cell.alignment = source.alignment.copy()
                    cell.border    = source.border.copy()
                    cell.fill      = source.fill.copy()
                  if fill_formulae and source.data_type == Cell.TYPE_FORMULA:
                    #print("Copying formula from cell %s%d to %s%d"%(col,row-1,col,row))
                    cell.value = re.sub(
                      "(\$?[A-Z]{1,3})%d"%(row - 1),
                      lambda m: m.group(1) + str(row),
                      source.value
                    )
```

Comment: Please see this snippet for fuller functionality: https://bitbucket.org/snippets/openpyxl/qyzKn

Answer (score 0):

Edited Nick's solution, this version takes a starting row, the number of rows to insert, and a filename, and inserts the necessary number of blank rows.

```
#! python 3

import openpyxl, sys

my_start = int(sys.argv[1])
my_rows = int(sys.argv[2])
str_wb = str(sys.argv[3])

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(str_wb)
old_sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet')
mcol = old_sheet.max_column
mrow = old_sheet.max_row
old_sheet.title = 'Sheet1.5'
wb.create_sheet(index=0, title='Sheet')

new_sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet')

for row_num in range(1, my_start):
    for col_num in range(1, mcol + 1):
        new_sheet.cell(row = row_num, column = col_num).value = old_sheet.cell(row = row_num, column = col_num).value

for row_num in range(my_start + my_rows, mrow + my_rows):
    for col_num in range(1, mcol + 1):
        new_sheet.cell(row = (row_num + my_rows), column = col_num).value = old_sheet.cell(row = row_num, column = col_num).value

wb.save(str_wb)
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
    openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.insert_rows(wbs,idx=row,amount=2)
```

Insert 2 rows before row==idx

See: http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to successfully use [Dallas's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1742878/dallas) answer, albeit with a few modifications for openpyxl 3.0.9. I'm posting the code here for anyone else wondering how to do it in 2022.

The differences are in:

- Adding the imports
- Changing `Cell.TYPE_FORMULA` to `TYPE_FORMULA`
- Adding type conversion using `str()` or `int()` where the required
- Updating definedNames

I'm new to Python so feel free to suggest any changes for this, but it's how I made it work.

```
import copy
import re
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
from openpyxl.cell.cell import TYPE_FORMULA

#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17299364/insert-row-into-excel-spreadsheet-using-openpyxl-in-python#71195832
def insert_rows(self, row_idx, cnt, above=True, copy_style=True, fill_formulae=True):
    """Inserts new (empty) rows into worksheet at specified row index.

    :param self: Worksheet
    :param row_idx: Row index specifying where to insert new rows.
    :param cnt: Number of rows to insert.
    :param above: Set True to insert rows above specified row index.
    :param copy_style: Set True if new rows should copy style of immediately above row.
    :param fill_formulae: Set True if new rows should take on formula from immediately above row, filled with references new to rows.

    Usage:

    * insert_rows(2, 10, above=True, copy_style=False)

    """
    CELL_RE  = re.compile("(?P<col>\$?[A-Z]+)(?P<row>\$?\d+)")

    row_idx = row_idx - 1 if above else row_idx

    def replace(m):
        row = m.group('row')
        prefix = "$" if row.find("$") != -1 else ""
        row = int(row.replace("$",""))
        row += cnt if row > row_idx else 0
        return m.group('col') + prefix + str(row)

    # First, we shift all cells down cnt rows...
    old_cells = set()
    old_fas   = set()
    new_cells = dict()
    new_fas   = dict()
    for c in self._cells.values():

        old_coor = c.coordinate

        # Shift all references to anything below row_idx
        if c.data_type == TYPE_FORMULA:
            c.value = CELL_RE.sub(
                replace,
                c.value
            )
            # Here, we need to properly update the formula references to reflect new row indices
            if old_coor in self.formula_attributes and 'ref' in self.formula_attributes[old_coor]:
                self.formula_attributes[old_coor]['ref'] = CELL_RE.sub(
                    replace,
                    self.formula_attributes[old_coor]['ref']
                )

        # Do the magic to set up our actual shift    
        if c.row > row_idx:
            old_coor = c.coordinate
            old_cells.add((c.row,c.column))
            c.row += cnt
            new_cells[(c.row,c.column)] = c
            if old_coor in self.formula_attributes:
                old_fas.add(old_coor)
                fa = self.formula_attributes[old_coor].copy()
                new_fas[c.coordinate] = fa

    for coor in old_cells:
        del self._cells[coor]
    self._cells.update(new_cells)

    for fa in old_fas:
        del self.formula_attributes[fa]
    self.formula_attributes.update(new_fas)

    # Next, we need to shift all the Row Dimensions below our new rows down by cnt...
    for row in range(len(self.row_dimensions)-1+cnt,row_idx+cnt,-1):
        new_rd = copy.copy(self.row_dimensions[row-cnt])
        new_rd.index = row
        self.row_dimensions[row] = new_rd
        del self.row_dimensions[row-cnt]

    # Now, create our new rows, with all the pretty cells
    row_idx += 1
    for row in range(row_idx,row_idx+cnt):
        # Create a Row Dimension for our new row
        new_rd = copy.copy(self.row_dimensions[row-1])
        new_rd.index = row
        self.row_dimensions[row] = new_rd
        for col in range(1,self.max_column):
            col = get_column_letter(col)
            cell = self[str(col)+str(row)]
            cell.value = None
            source = self[str(col)+str(row-1)]
            if copy_style:
                cell.number_format = source.number_format
                cell.font      = copy.copy(source.font)
                cell.alignment = copy.copy(source.alignment)
                cell.border    = copy.copy(source.border)
                cell.fill      = copy.copy(source.fill)
            if fill_formulae and source.data_type == TYPE_FORMULA:
                s_coor = source.coordinate
                if s_coor in self.formula_attributes and 'ref' not in self.formula_attributes[s_coor]:
                    fa = self.formula_attributes[s_coor].copy()
                    self.formula_attributes[cell.coordinate] = fa
                # print("Copying formula from cell %s%d to %s%d"%(col,row-1,col,row))
                cell.value = re.sub(
                    "(\$?[A-Z]{1,3}\$?)%d"%(row - 1),
                    lambda m: m.group(1) + str(row),
                    source.value
                )   
                cell.data_type = TYPE_FORMULA

    # Check for Merged Cell Ranges that need to be expanded to contain new cells
    for cr_idx, cr in enumerate(self.merged_cells.ranges):
        self.merged_cells.ranges[cr_idx] = CELL_RE.sub(
            replace,
            str(cr)
        )

    # Update all defined names
    wb :Workbook = self.parent
    for definedName in wb.defined_names.definedName:
        ref :str = definedName.attr_text
        parts = ref.split("!")
        if parts[0].strip("'") == self.title:
            definedName.attr_text = CELL_RE.sub(replace, ref)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem.

However, using the xlwings module as a trick, I was able to easily solve it by running the macro of Excel.

But what's unfortunate is ".xlsm" extension should be used.

Python Code

```
import xlwings as xw

# 엑셀 매크로파일 열기(path는 매크로 파일이 있는 경로)
wb = xw.Book("test.xlsm")

# 엑셀 VBA의 매크로 함수 'test'를 파이썬 함수로 지정
macro_test = wb.macro('매크로1')

# VBA 함수 실행
macro_test()

# 함수를 실행한 엑셀파일 따로 저장하기
wb.save("test.xlsm")

# WorkBook 객체 닫기
wb.close()
```

VBA Code

```
Sub 매크로1()
'
' 매크로1 매크로
'

'
    Rows("7:7").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
End Sub
```

Reference Contents : [Writing a VBA macro to call a python script using xlwings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45468427/writing-a-vba-macro-to-call-a-python-script-using-xlwings)

If you want to use ".xlsx", you can take it in the same way as below.

```
import xlwings as xw
from win32com.client import constants as c

wb = xw.Book("2.xlsx")
sheet = wb.sheets['Sheet1']

sheet.range('6:6').api.Insert(Shift=c.xlDown)

wb.save()

wb.close()
```

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately there isn't really a better way to do in that read in the file, and use a library like xlwt to write out a new excel file (with your new row inserted at the top).  Excel doesn't work like a database that you can read and and append to.  You unfortunately just have to read in the information and manipulate in memory and write out to what is essentially a new file.