# Spreadsheets: insert into columns as if a stack

Tags: c++, open-source, row, spreadsheet, xls

First: I know this would be much easier if it was a `.CSV` but that is not possible (I'd 'a written the code in the time I wrote this post).

I want to insert numbers given by the user along with a time-stamp into a spreadsheet. There will be a graph in the spreadsheet that automatically generates based on columns `a` and `b`, hence the need to not be a `.CSV`. Column `A` holds Double-Floats of range 0 through 500 and Column `B` holds Date and Time information. Inserted rows must be at the top, thus pushing all existing data down by one row, each time.

I've been writing this manually and I think its time to stop doing that. I don't really care what language it is done in, but I would prefer C/C++ using at most the boost libraries. All libraries MUST be open-source. OS is Linux and input should from terminal or at least be given to the program as a parameter, such that the user's input could be piped into the program.

I found this, but I'm not sure if it is the best method as I'm not necessarily locked into python.
[Insert row into Excel spreadsheet using openpyxl in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17299364/insert-row-into-excel-spreadsheet-using-openpyxl-in-python)

Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: It is easier to manipulate the Excel spreadsheet with MS Office native VBA. You might add one more tag:VBA to your question.

Comment: Is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications what VBA means? If so I don't believe that will help me from linux terminal. I am going to add that to the original question as that was probably not clear, sorry.

Comment: OK. Now I know you want to operate excel file on linux with MS Office environment.

Comment: I think Python and the xlwt and xlrd libraries almost do what I want, if only I could get them to modify existing spreadsheets rather than just reading or just writing...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this? A C library that read Excel (xls) files: http://libxls.sourceforge.net.

Hope this meet your need.

An alternative: http://www.libxl.com, more powerful but not open source.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Unfortunately, at this time they don't work for me because libxls doesn't save, and libxl isn't free.