# how to get all the urls of a website using a crawler or a scraper?

Tags: python, url, web-crawler, scraper

i have to get many urls from a website and then i've to copy these in an excel file.
I'm looking for an automatic way to do that. The website is structured having a main page with about 300 links and inside of each link there are 2 or 3 links that are interesting for me.
Any suggestions ?

Comment: Are you interested in programming, and if yes, what language?

Comment: yes. Actually any language but i would prefer Python

Answer (score 1):

If you want to develop your solution in Python then I can recommend [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) framework.

As far as inserting the data into an Excel sheet is concerned, there are ways to do it directly, see for example here: [Insert row into Excel spreadsheet using openpyxl in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17299364/insert-row-into-excel-spreadsheet-using-openpyxl-in-python) , but you can also write the data into a CSV file and then import it into Excel.

Answer (score 1):

If the links are in the html... You can use beautiful soup. This has worked for me in the past.

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = 'http://yourUrl.com'
opened = urllib2.urlopen(page)
soup = BeautifulSoup(opened)

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print (link.get('href'))
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried selenium or urllib?.urllib is faster than selenium
http://useful-snippets.blogspot.in/2012/02/simple-website-crawler-with-selenium.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use beautiful soup for parsing ,
 [[http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/]](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

More information about docs here http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

**I won't suggest scrappy because you don't need that for work you described in your question.**

For e.g. this code will use urllib2 library to open a google homepage and find all links in that output in the form of list

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data=urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com').read()
soup=BeautifulSoup(data)
print soup.find_all('a')
```

For handling excel files take a look at http://www.python-excel.org