# Issues with openpyxl: Attempting to insert dictionary into new excel file

Tags: python, excel, dictionary

I am new to programming.
I am learning to write in the python language. I am currently trying to put an existing dictionary into a new excel file. I have a feeling that because I have a dictionary may be the issue?
I am using openpyxl.

I am getting an error message(AttributeError: 'WriteOnlyWorksheet' object has no attribute 'cell' ) whenever I attempt to insert the dictionary. However I can write to a simple cell with no issue. 
It is when trying to fill in large data into a column that I get the error.

```
 #Writing a new excel file with key information
    print("Would you like to create a new excel document?")
    b_input = input("Type: 'Y' or 'N' -> ").lower()
    if b_input == "y":
        wb = Workbook(write_only=True)
        ws = wb.create_sheet()

        print("I can only put in the contract status and serial numbers together in a file.")
        c_input = input("Would you like to do that? Type: 'Y' or 'N' -> ")
        if c_input == 'y':
            ws.cell(row=r, column=1).value = excel_info


    wb.save('new_test_book.xlsx')
```

Comment: I have not, I shall take a look !
edit: object has no attribute write 

:P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the [write_only mode.docs](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/optimized.html#write-only-mode):

> In a write-only workbook, rows can only be added with append(). It is not possible to write (or read) cells at arbitrary locations with cell() or iter_rows().

that's why error tells you there is no attribute cell so use `append()` instead.

You can also refer to this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29354868/how-can-openpyxl-write-list-data-in-sheet) for more help and understanding.

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: No problem at all, wish i could help more @JulianSilvestri