# python openpyxl append data

Tags: python, openpyxl

I would like to "append" the list to the sheet through Python openxyxl.
However,  I would like to enter this result from column B6.
Please tell me how to input the data to the desired location using "append".

```
for l in Lists:
 Sheet.append(l)
```

Comment: Check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29354868/how-can-openpyxl-write-list-data-in-sheet

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.