# xlsxwriter: How to insert a new row

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

Using xlsxwriter, how do I insert a new row to an Excel worksheet? For instance, there is an existing data table at the cell range A1:G10 of the Excel worksheet, and I want to insert a row (A:A) to give it some space for the title of the report.

I looked through the documentation here http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html, but couldn't find such method.

```
import xlsxwriter

# Create a workbook and add a worksheet.
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Expenses01.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheet.insert_row(1)  # This method doesn't exist
```

Comment: Can you use xlrd to read the existing file?

Comment: Xlsxwriter creates workbooks/worksheets from new. It cannot read an existing xlsx file and modify it. Therefore inserting a new row is not required. Plan out what and where you want to enter the data into the sheet.

Answer (score 7):

December 2021, this is still not a possibility. You can get around this by doing some planning, and then writing your dataframe starting on different row. Building on the example from the [xlsxwriter documentation](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [10, 20, 30, 20, 15, 30, 45]})
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('my_excel_spreadsheet.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
with writer as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow = 4) # <<< notice the startrow here
```

And then, you can write to the earlier rows as mentioned in other comments:

```
workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
worksheet.write(row, 0, 'Some Text') # <<< Then you can write to a different row
```

Not quite the `insert()` method we want, but better than nothing.

I have found that the planning involved in this process is not really ever something I can get around, even if I didn't have this problem. When I reach the stage where I am taking my data to excel, I have to do a little 'by hand' work in order to make the excel sheet pretty enough for human consumption, which is the whole point of moving things to excel. So, I don't look at the need to pre-plan my start rows as too much out of my way.

Comment: Using `startrow` did what I wanted, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

By using openpyxl you can insert iew rows and columns

```
import openpyxl

file = "xyz.xlsx"
#loading XL sheet bassed on file name provided by user
book = openpyxl.load_workbook(file)
#opening sheet whose index no is 0
sheet = book.worksheets[0]

#insert_rows(idx, amount=1) Insert row or rows before row==idx, amount will be no of 
#rows you want to add and it's optional
sheet.insert_rows(13)
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately this is not something `xlsxwriter` can do.

`openpyxl` is a good alternative to `xlsxwriter`, and if you are starting a new project do not use `xlsxwriter`.

Currently `openpyxl` can not insert rows, but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30839396/1705337) is an extension class for `openpyxl` that can.

`openpyxl` also allows reading of excel documents, which `xlsxwriter` does not.

Comment: Why should I prefer `openpxl` to `xlsxwriter`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
import xlsxwriter

wb = Workbook("name.xlsx")
ws = wb.add_worksheet("sheetname")

# Write a blank cell
ws.write_blank(0, 0, None, cell_format)
ws.write_blank('A2', None, cell_format)
```

Here is the official documentation:
[Xlsxwriter worksheet.write_blank() method](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#write_blank)

Another alternative is to merge a few blank columns

```
ws.merge_range('A1:D1', "")
```

Otherwise you'll need to run a loop to write each blank cell

```
# Replace 1 for the row number you need
for c in range(0,10):
   ws.write_blank(1, c, None, cell_format)
```

Inserting a row is equivalent to adding +1 to your row count. Technically there is no need for a "blank row" method and I'm pretty sure that's why it isn't there.

Answer (score -3):

you should use`write`

read this: `set_column(first_col, last_col, width, cell_format, options)`

for example:

```
import xlsxwriter
workbook =xlsxwriter.Workbook('xD.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheet.write(row, col,     'First Name')
workbook.close()
```

Comment: Thanks but, my question was about inserting a row, not writing to a row.

Answer (score -3):

I am very much unhappy with the answers. The library *xlxsWriter* tends to perform most of the operations easily.
To add a row in the existing worksheet , you can

```
    wb.write_row(rowNumber,columnNumber,listToAdd)
```

Comment: This answer does not add a new row, it just writes data into an existing row...