# For loop using XlsxWriter with Python Excel

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

I'm trying to make a loop where new values are put into a new row in the same excel sheet. I've succefully made a loop where for every new ''sampleid'' it made a new sheet but now I want for every new ''sampleid'' to do a new row with the values. This is the code im currently using, how can I modify it for the results I want?

```
        if sampleid!="000":
            print sampleid
            print "Isotope \t", "A (Bq/kg) +/- 1 sd \t MDA (Bq/kg)"
            #sampleid = workbook.add_worksheet()
           
            if create_an_excel_file_with_one_table:
                worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet(sampleid)
                worksheet.set_column('A:AA', 30)

            for i in range(len(activity)):
                if isotopes[i]=="Pb-210" :
                        worksheet.write(i+2, 0, isotopes[i])
                        worksheet.write(i+2, 1,str(np.round(activity_pbc[i]/mass,8)))
                        worksheet.write(i+2, 2, '+/-')
                        worksheet.write(i+2, 3,str(np.round(sigma_activity_pbc[i]/mass,8)))
                        worksheet.write(i+2, 4,str(MDA[i]/mass))     
                worksheet.write("B1", sampleid, bold)
                worksheet.write("A1", "Sampleid:", bold)
                worksheet.write("A2", "Isotope", bold)
                worksheet.write("B2","Activity (Bq/kg)", bold)
                worksheet.write("C2",'+/-', bold)
                worksheet.write("D2",'1 sd', bold)
                worksheet.write("E2","MDA (Bq/kg)", bold)
                worksheet.write(row,3,'Detector:', bold)
                worksheet.write(row,4,detector)
                worksheet.set_default_row(hide_unused_rows=True)

    workbook.close()
```

Comment: IS the problem solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe adding a new row with `xlsxwriter` is possible. `xlsxwriter` is merely a module for writing files in any `XLSX` file format. You can see [here](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter#xlsxwriter) for more on what's offered.

I would recommend using `openpyxl` for this as adding rows with that is much easier, see here for a comprehensive answer on how that's done - [Insert row into Excel spreadsheet using openpyxl in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17299364/insert-row-into-excel-spreadsheet-using-openpyxl-in-python)

Comment: There are also more well-elaborated answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36957035/xlsxwriter-how-to-insert-a-new-row)